# Add new keys to a JSON file without losing existing information (Node JS)

Tags: nodejs, json, discord.js

I have been trying to do this for about 10 hours, and it's probably very easy, but for more things that I have tried and searched on the internet, I have not been able to do what I wanted, so I come here as a last hope.

I'm using a JSON file to use as a database for my Discord server. I've written a system where it detects if the user has data in the JSON file, and if not, creates new data in the JSON file for that user.

The problem comes when I try to add new data, because it replaces the old data with the new one, instead of adding the new data below the existing one.

```html
deb = false
i = 0

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    //Check if the user exists
    data = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./json/data.json"))
    while (deb === false) {
        if (data["Users"][i].ID === message.author.id){
            deb = true
            console.log("User found " + i)
        }
        else{
            console.log("User not found " + i)
            i++;
            if(data["Users"][i]){
                //Nothing happens
            }
            else{
                //The user not exist, so we create new data
                const newData = {
                    Users: [
                        {
                            ID: message.author.id,
                            Money: 100
                        },
                    ]
                }

                fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2), function writeJSON(err) {
                if (err) return console.log(err);
                });
                deb = true
            }
        }
      }
    deb = false
    i = 0
})
```

The closest I've come to getting what I want is by adding the existing data to the new one adding "data":

```html
if(data["Users"][i]){
                //Nothing happens
            }
            else{
                const newData = {
                    data,
                    Users: [
                        {
                            ID: message.author.id,
                            Money: 100
                        },
                    ]
                }
```

But if I do that, the word "data" is added to the json file and the existing users are repeated.

Comment: Hello Friend, your Post has a problem and is written in a different Language than the expected on the Site; I recommend that you translate it into Spanish.

Comment: Hola, Bienvenid@ al Sitio, veo que eres nuev@ te recomendaria hacer el [tour] para que conoscas mejor el sitio, He mirado tu post y te comento lo siguiente:, Puedes leer este Articulo [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, Puedes leer este Articulo [mre], También es importante que sepas que preguntas son mal vistas [help/dont-ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You are writting in English in a Spanish forum.**

The problem is you are writting only the new data, replacing the entire file.

This is the problem

```
const newData = Users: [{ID: message.author.id, Money: 100},]}
fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(newData, null, 2), ...)
```

This is the solution

```
const newData = Users: [{ID: message.author.id, Money: 100},]}
data.Users.push(newData)
fs.writeFile(fileName, JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), ...)
```